# HighlightGraph highlighting the vertices but not the edges of a subgraph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm trying to highlight the path between two vertices, and it seems that `PathGraph` along with `HighlightGraph` is what I should use. However, only the vertices of the path graph get highlighted. The edges between the vertices are not being highlighted.

Here's my code:

```
G = 
  Graph[
    {1 -> 3, 1 -> 9, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 3, 3 -> 7, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 8, 4 -> 2, 9 -> 2, 
     9 -> 10, 5 -> 9, 2 -> 5, 2 -> 7, 10 -> 2, 7 -> 10, 7 -> 8, 7 -> 2, 8 -> 6, 
     8 -> 7, 6 -> 8, 6 -> 7 }, 
    GraphStyle -> "SmallNetwork"]
```

I'll get the following:

[image]

Now for my attempt at highlighting the shortest path between vertex 1 and 5:

```
HighlightGraph[G, PathGraph[FindShortestPath[G, 1, 5]]]
```

I get the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? I'd like for the arrows leading from vertex 1 to 5 to be highlighted too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method one:

```
HighlightGraph[G, 
 PathGraph[FindShortestPath[G, 1, 5], DirectedEdges -> True]]
```

[image]

#### Method two:

```
HighlightGraph[G, Subgraph[G, FindShortestPath[G, 1, 5]]]
```

[image]

---

BTW, I strongly recommend avoiding the use of a single capital letter as a variable name. Note that all the characters in the phase "ONE DICK" are pre-defined in the `` System` `` context in *Mathematica*.

Comment: Method 2 is not so good. It highlights edge `5 -> 9`, which is not part of the path.

Comment: Oh! I didn't know DirectedEdges was needed. Thank you so much. And noted on that point, I will change it.

Comment: @m_goldberg I mean this two method face to two cases.But I don't know which one the OP need.